# angulargrid dynamic height based on row count

Tags: angular-grid

I am using **angulargrid** library for a table grid. I am trying to implement dynamic height based on row count on the angulargrid and make my table fit the whole page and not scroll the data in a small table as is now.To do that I wrote a function that could help achieve this task.

```
My code: angularjs

  var columnDefs = [

  {headerName:”headerName1” field: “field1”}
  {headerName:”headerName2” field: “field2”}

];
 var rowData = [];
 scope.gridOptions = {
                       columnDefs:              columnDefs,
                       rowData:                 null,
                       pinnedColumnCount:       2,
                       dontUseScrolls:       true,
                       angularCompileRows:      true,
                       enableSorting:           true,
                       enableCellExpressions:    true,
                       enableFilter:            true,
                       rowSelection:           'multiple',
                       groupSuppressAutoColumn: true,
                       groupIncludeFooter:      false,
                       groupHidePivotColumns:true,
                       groupUseEntireRow:       true,


    function setHeight(more) {
         scope.height = (($scope.gridOptions.data.length * 30) + 30);
         if (more) {
               scope.height += more
         }
       scope.gridOptions.api.gridHeight = scope.height;


  HTML:
 <div 
  ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" >

 </div>
```

It does not resize the grid dynamically. Nothing happens exactly to my data. Can someone please help me why this is not working?